# Compare same tables in 2 different databases and 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 servers, one named DB2 (cloud), and one named OUS (on prem).

I have 2 databases, one named version1 (cloud), and one named version2 (on prem).

A person is adding a column in xyz entity on the version1 (cloud) database, and this new column in xyz entity must be added to version2 (on prem) database.

I am facing the issue of schema mismatch due to unmatched column, and I need a SQL query to address this issue.

Comment: Please post your code as actual text and not a picture. Someone here will likely want to cut/paste from your example and that is not possible from a picture.

Comment: No DBMS product adds columns "randomly" - they are only added if someone (or something) runs the appropriate `ALTER` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use Schema Compare Tool, either in SSMS/VS or RedGate Compare

It will generate alter script for you.